# Use a mergefield to import data from a text file (MS Word 2010)

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, mergefield

I am using mail merge in MS Word 2010. Data comes from an Excel spreadsheet:

```
Last Name           First Name          Group
Smith               Oliver              F1
Jones               Amelia              B2
Taylor              Emma                B2
Williams            Jack                C1
```

Let us say that we have the following mergefields: *"LASTNAME"*, *"FIRSTNAME"* and *"GROUP"*.

In my document, I would like to add a paragraph, specific to the group. Word would look for this paragraph in a file called *"GROUP"*.txt:

```
B1.txt:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

B2.txt:
Sed auctor turpis sed nisl ultricies volutpat.

C1.txt:
Vestibulum vel interdum metus, quis accumsan tortor.
```

This is one idea among others. These paragraphs could also come another source, such as an Excel worksheet or a CSV file.

Do you have an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to tell you that I found a satisfactory solution to my problem by writing a small VBA script. It works in three steps:

1. Get the value of the desired mergefield (eg. "B2")

   ```
   ' source: 4th post, from dmaruca, on VBForum thread Nr 549587
   GroupVal = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Group").Value
   ```
2. Import the content of the related textfile (eg. "C:\B2.TXT")

   ```
   GroupText = ImportTextFile("C:\" & GroupVal & ".Txt")

   ' VBA Code Snippet #22 from Allan Chara (Excel MVP)
   Function ImportTextFile(strFile As String) As String
     Open strFile For Input As #1
     ImportTextFile = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
     Close #1
   End Function
   ```
3. Insert the text

   ```
   ' see Microsoft KB #212682
   Selection.TypeText (GroupText)
   ```